# Remove @Override annotation  related to android.location methods

Tags: android, location, overriding

I have just reinstalled Android SDK, Java JDK, and Eclipse Indigo back on to my laptop (after a hardware crash) and now I am getting errors within my android projects relating to the following:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "GPS Enabled ",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "GPS Disabled ",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Eclipse tells me that I should remove @Override annotation in order to resolve the issue. These errors only seem to be related to android.location methods. I know that before the hardware crash the code worked fine without any errors, so I am not sure what the problem is. If someone could provide some advice, it would greatly be appreciated.

For the reinstall, I used the following:

Eclipse 64bit,
Android SDK 32bit,
Java JDK 32bit

Comment: Why not just remove @Override?  I don't remember it being needed...

Comment: Check your compiler compliance level; @Override for interface methods is 1.6+.

Answer (score 3):

Please check the JDK version, if it is not 1.6 eclipse gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Override` annotation is used to signify that a method overrides a method in the parent class. It is useful to get compiler errors and [other benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why).

If you are getting errors it probably means that you are not extending the superclass correctly or it does not have those methods.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project ->properties->java compiler-> Set compiler compliance level to to 1.6 instead of 1.5 ... Because annotation support in code is provide in 1.6 compiler not in 1.5 compiler.